# My CSS Navigation Bar's Background color property isn't working

Tags: html, css, django, frontend, background-color

I am trying to create a navigation bar with a search box. When I insert the elements in the navbar and set the display to inline-block in css, the navigation bar's background color is not being displayed.

My HTML navbar,

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family:  'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0);
  margin:0;
}

.main_nav{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255.1);
}

.main_nav li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
{%load static%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{%static 'css/styles.css'%}">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="main_nav">
      <ul>
        <li><img width="80" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/IMDB_Logo_2016.svg/1200px-IMDB_Logo_2016.svg.png"></li>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>
          <form method="GET" action="{%url 'search-view'%}">
            <input type="search" name="query" id="query" placeholder="search movie">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>       
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section>
  {%block content%}
  {%endblock%}
  </section>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The `.main_nav` background color doesn't seem to be working. I am also open to a better way to give the same output with the background color.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is due to the asterisk (*) rule set

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family:  'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0);
  margin:0;
}
```

> Asterisk (*) is known as the CSS universal selectors. It can be used to select all types > of elements in an HTML page.

To solve the issue, remove `background-color: rgba(0,0,0);` from the universal selector.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using * for `background-color`,separate it to `body` tag, try below

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family:  'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
  
  margin:0;
}
body {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0);
}

.main_nav{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255.1);
}
```

Comment: wow,that worked! Pretty sure it's a rookie mistake,thanks a lot!